# ¿Cómo generar una ruta que pase por varios puntos en Gmap C# ? (actualización de problematica)

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-api, rutas

Hola estoy realizando un generador de ruta de entrega, la información se encuentra en una base de dato que se encuentra en el DatagridView2, se trata de tener varios puntos de entrega y trazar una ruta que pase por cada uno.

Este es el código sobre el que estoy trabajando:

```
private void btn_comollegar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MapRoute rutasdireccion;
        GMapRoute rutaobtenida;
        GMapOverlay caparutas;
        // creamos las variables para almacenar los datos
        double lat, lng;
        // tomamos los datos del grid
        for (int filas = 0; filas < DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; filas++)
        {

            lat = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView2.Rows[filas].Cells[2].Value);
            lng = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView2.Rows[filas].Cells[3].Value);

            //En este apartado añades un punto a tu lista
            puntos.Add(new PointLatLng(lat, lng));

            //Si queremos utilizar 2 elementos de la lista puntos debemos estar seguros de que existen, al menos,
            //esos 2 elementos, es decir en la primera iteración del bucle no debo realizar esta parte
            if (puntos.Count() >= 2)
            {
                rutasdireccion = GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(puntos[filas-1], puntos[filas], false, false, 15);
                rutaobtenida = new GMapRoute(rutasdireccion.Points, "Ruta Ubicación");
                caparutas = new GMapOverlay("capa de la ruta");
                caparutas.Routes.Add(rutaobtenida);
                gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(caparutas);
                // para actualizar
                //gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom + 1;
                //gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom - 1;
                gMapControl1.UpdateRouteLocalPosition(rutaobtenida);
            }

         }

     }
```

Al correr el código y seleccionar el botón marca el siguiente error:

[image: <code>introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí</code>]

Como pueden observar en variable locales,las variables: rutasdireccion, rutaobtenida y caparutas se encuentran como null, sin embargo no se como corregir esta excepción. de antemano gracias.

Comment: La linea 282 no esta devolviendo nada en la funcion GetRoute, el error se arregla inicializando  la variable rutadireccion, pero si no te devuelve en rutadireccion.Points puede que tengas el mismo problema

Comment: @VictorPerdomo¿ Cómo podría inicializar siendo que no me ha permitido de ninguna de las maneras que he intetado?

Comment: aquí esta la razón por la que llega nulo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693023/gmap-net-route-is-returning-null

Comment: @VictorPerdomo excelente probaré utilizando el bingmapprovider

Comment: @VictorPerdomo ya logré resolver el código muchas gracias por la inf.